# Spritekit frame by frame animation / performance issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, sprite-kit

I'm new into developing but after searching and didn't able to find specific answers, I wanted to open a thread, if my questions sound beginner, it's normal,  I'm completely new into this.

Currently I'm working on a simple project;

I'm using a spritekit scene in every view controller which includes a color sprite with AnimateWithtextures Action. It includes 12 different images so it's a frame by frame animation.

Although I'm having weird performance issue after a while (currently app includes just 3 spritekit scene / 4 view controller) and iphone gets hot quickly. So I assume there's a problem, I have some specific concerns which I can ask;

1 - I started project with **single view app** template, should I choose **game** template? (I added `import SpriteKit` into code and linked spritekit library though, so this shouldn't be a problem)

2 - Could be a wrong choice using color sprite for AnimateWithtextures Action?

3 - I used instruments, there's no leak, cpu usage is mostly over %150 though.

4 - Images are png8, not transparent, frame rate is 12 per second for every animation. Is there anything else I can do for optimization?

5 - I used seperate asset catalog/folder for every view controller/scene. Does this affect anything or not?

Any other questions & suggestions are welcome.

Comment: 3 spritekit scene at the same time? Very unusual! And I doubt it was build for such usage. In general: more intensive animations ==> more intensive CPU usage. You may rethink your way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my comment:

1. No problem, templates are just pre-built configs; then customizing any template the way you want is exactly the same.
2. Interface Builder `Color Sprite` is just instance of `SKSpriteNode` exactly what you need for texture animation
3. My comment suggest that 3 scenes with intensive animations at the same time is probably not the best way to proceed (As you didn't describe your intention more precisely, I can't answer more)
4. No, except ensure that textures aren't resized too frequently. Size fitting may reduce in some context CPU usage
5. No effect. It's just a matter of project structuring.

Comment: 3 - Not same time, every view controller have one scene, so I have 2 storyboard with a static image (including launchscreen.storyboard), and 3 storyboard with 3 spritekit scene (1 per 1)

Comment: If it is not at the same then consider scene switching

Comment: I assume every loaded scene keeps animating at background even when it's not visible, right?